# jquery ajax event.preventDefault() cancel the submit action of form

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

**I create a form in html:**

```
<form id="flog" action="https://localhost/book.php" method="post">
                    <div id="inputUser">
                        <label for="userName">User</label>
                        <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
                    </div>
                    <div id="inputPass">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                    </div>
                    <div id="savePassword">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="savePassword" value="CheckSavePAssword">Save password
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Acceptar">
                </form>
```

And I create a submit function with JQuery:

```
$("#flog").submit(function(event) {
var savePassword = false;
if($("#CheckSavePAssword").is(':checked')) {
  savePassword = true;
}
var login = new Object();
login.username = $("#userName").val();
login.pass = $("#password").val();
login.savePassword = savePassword;
var jlogin = JSON.stringify(login);
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: "./checkLogin.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {"dataLogin" : jlogin},
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
      console.log("okk "+data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
});
```

But if i don't put "event.preventDefault()" the ajax function does not run, but this line (event.preventDefault()) canceling the submit form action.What is the problem?

Comment: what do you mean by cancelling the form action?

Comment: `preventDefault()` is there to stop the page from reloading. Without it, the form will simply send the user to `book.php` instead of loading the data asynchronously. That's why the function won't run without it. OTOH the PHP script may not capture the  POST data. Have you checked this?

Comment: Don't use ajax leave it to default, if you want to redirect your page book.php...

Comment: `https://localhost/book.php` use relative url instead just `book.php`

Comment: you are confused...tell us what is your requirement >>> do you want to check login using ajax and then redirect to book.php based on the result from checklogin.php ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `preventDefault()`, you prevent the form from undergoing a traditional POST where your page would be submitted and reloaded. You need to use a JavaScript event handler if you want to give the user some feedback after your AJAX call.

Comment: @susheel I'm new around here, care to explain? He asked a question, I wrote an answer

Comment: its not an answer. his question itself is not clear what he trying to do..how can you say that this is the answer.. when we are not clear, it should be a comment

Comment: He asks what the problem is with his form submission, I don't see how his question is unclear. But I'll keep it in mind, thanks.

Comment: `action="https://localhost/book.php"` and ajax call with `url: "./checkLogin.php"` ?? if he doesn't use ajax it would go to book.php

Comment: The action is likely an echo of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], where the form is written/prepared. Since he's not using JavaScript to extract the action attribute, he's simply chosen to write his backend code elsewhere

Comment: but he seems to be thinking that page should refresh and normal submit should work(page should redirect to book.php).
`canceling the submit form action.` then why to use ajax..thats the confusion i am talking about